# Identifying data binding errors in WinForm apps

Tags: winforms, data-binding

Is there anything in WinForms that you can enable (eg. a Trace Listener) to get logging/diagnostics for missing/incorrect data binding?

I know with a WPF application, that you can see data binding warnings logged to the output window in Visual Studio when running the application under the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No but usually incorrect binding will result an exception or incorrect behaviour which is always obvious.